# System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure Exception: KeyError: '__main__' Azure timer trigger function using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to build a ***Azure Timer Trigger Function using Python***. But when i am trying to execute some function to do some calculation from database in the "***main***" function, its through me a failure Exception(Please see the image.) Can some one share your experience please?

[image]

Comment: Can you please check if the [azure functions core tool](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools) is updated to V4 and see if the same error exists.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its worked after install core tool..

Answer (score 0):

This might be a version issue of [azure functions core tool](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools). Updating the Function Tool to V4 could resolve the issue.

Also you can refer [[BUG] Local Debugging Fails With "KeyError: '**main**'"](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/887) where they were dealing with a similar issue.